# Scraping data off transfermarkt page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the table from [this page](https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/laliga/legionaereeinsaetze/wettbewerb/ES1/saison_id/2020/altersklasse/alle/option/spiele/plus/1) using BeautifulSoup and to put it into a DataFrame.
Currently I have tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/laliga/legionaereeinsaetze/wettbewerb/ES1/saison_id/2020/altersklasse/alle/option/spiele/plus/1", headers= {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find_all("tbody")[1].find_all("a")
for result in results:
    print(result.text)
```

And the result I get is

```
Athletic
27
26
1
99.9 %
0.1 %

CA Osasuna
28
22
6
84.5 %
15.5 %

SD Huesca
27
20
7
82.7 %
17.3 %
...
```

I have tried slicing the data using *print(result.text[0])* to try and split the results but have had no success in trying to turn this into a DataFrame. Any other way to do this?

Comment: Could you please add to your answer the code you used to split the result?

Answer (score 0):

first find that table and use `pd.read_html` to parse table as `str` it will return as list and create `df` from it

```
results = soup.find("table",class_="items")
df=pd.read_html(str(results))[0]

df.drop(columns=['wappen',"% minutes foreign players"],inplace=True)
df.columns=['Club', 'Players used', 'Non-foreigners played',
       'Used foreign players', '% minutes non-foreigners',
       '% minutes foreign players']
```

Image:
[image]